# Circle from two points

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, circles

[image]
$\vec{u}=\vec{SR}, \vec{v}= \vec{PR}$ where R is any point on the circle.

For a specific $\lambda$ a unique circle, that goes through P and S, can be described thus: $$\tan{a}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\Leftrightarrow \cos{a}-\lambda\sin{a}=0$$$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|(\cos{a}-\lambda\sin{a})=0$$$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos{a}-\lambda\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=0$$

$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\sin{a}$ for all points on the circle since $$\sin{a}=\sin{180-a}$$

$|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos{a}\ne \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$ for all points on the circle, since $$\cos{a}\ne \cos{180-a}$$

However, if we choose $\lambda=1$ and calculate $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}-\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=0$ with coordinates, we get the equation for a circle:
$$x^2+y^2-y-x=0\Leftrightarrow (x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2=0.5$$ Am I wrong in saying that $|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos{a}\ne \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally understood my mistake and am sorry to have posted this questions in multiple forms to get an answer. I got the answer from @Patrick Hew, and it is so simple that I feel very dumb. But such is math.

The dot product is changing sings when the angle between vectors change from a to 180-a, but so does the sign of the crossproduct. Since both $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ change sings when the angle between them change, the equation is still true.

$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=-\vec{v}\times\vec{u}$